# Exception on service activation in mock OSGi context

Tags: unit-testing, osgi, aem, sling

In my Maven project, I've created a simple OSGi service that does nothing but accepts one reference:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@Component
public class MyFoo {
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory factory;
}
```

Then, using osgi-mock tutorial, I've created the following test class:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.junit.OsgiContext;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyFooTest {
    @Rule
    public OsgiContext mockContext = new OsgiContext();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ResourceResolverFactory mockFactory = Mockito.mock(ResourceResolverFactory.class);

        mockContext.registerService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, mockFactory);
        mockContext.registerInjectActivateService(new MyFoo());
    }

}
```

The test crashes on the last line with the following exception:

```
org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.NoScrMetadataException: No OSGi SCR metadata found for class MyFoo

    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiServiceUtil.injectServices(OsgiServiceUtil.java:381)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockOsgi.injectServices(MockOsgi.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.context.OsgiContextImpl.registerInjectActivateService(OsgiContextImpl.java:141)
    at MyFooTest.testGetResolver(MyFooTest.java:22)
//snippet
```

Following the advice on the internet, I've reached [this configuration guide](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/faqs/apache-felix-bundle-plugin-faq.html#use-scr-metadata-generated-by-bnd-in-unit-tests) and ensured that my `pom.xml` has exactly this configuration for `maven-bundle-plugin` - this however did not resolve the issue.

Any idea where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried replicating your issue, ran into the same exception initially and got it working now. Issue is probably due to spoiled classpath because of transitive dependencies between `maven-scr-plugin` and `maven-bundle-plugin`.

Ensure you have the following in place:

- Use osgi-mock 2.x mock dependency which is OSGI R6 compatible. This is what I used.

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.6</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  ```
- Remove `scr` maven plugins and dependencies (`maven-scr-plugin` and `org.apache.felix.scr`) as this leads to classpath conflicts when used in conjunction with OSGi R6 annotations. This is the version of `maven-bundle-plugin` I've used. I picked up all the required dependencies from [here](https://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/osgi/using-osgi-annotations-aem6-2/).

  ```
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.2.0</version>
          </plugin>
  ```
- Ensure your plugin build section contains the required configurations to generate the required DS metadata. You can refer to the felix docs that you've linked for more info on this.

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>scr-metadata</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>manifest</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <exportScr>true</exportScr>
              <instructions>
                  <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.aem.chula.chula</Bundle-SymbolicName>

                  <Sling-Model-Packages>
                    com.aem.models
                  </Sling-Model-Packages>

                  <_dsannotations>*</_dsannotations>
                  <_metatypeannotations>*</_metatypeannotations>
              </instructions>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Do a `mvn clean install` which will generate the DS output in `/OSG-INF`.
- Run your tests. I've used `MockitoJunitRunner`, should work fine with `PowerMock` as well.

[image]

Comment: Adding dependency on `org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock` seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the ds-annotations dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.10</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

As described in http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin-use.html